# wp_enqueue_style Does Not Behave As Documented

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following written in a driver:

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_css_file' );
 function add_css_file()
 {
      // Tried this prior:
      // $path = ABSPATH . "/wp-content/plugins/this_plugin/css/";
      // wp_register_style( 'css_file', $path.'css_file.css' );

      wp_register_style( 'css_file', 'http://subdomain.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/this_plugin/css/css_file.css' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'css_file' );
 }
```

The string "css_file" does not appear in the View Source HTML and the CSS rules defined therein do not take effect.

Comment: Your syntax is correct...but why are you including an absolute path like that? You should be using something like: `plugins_url( 'this_plugin/css/css_file.css' )`

Comment: @rnevius is right. You cannot use file system path, so the commented out code is 100% incorect and you don't need it.

Comment: Use plugins_url function instead of absolute path may be a solution to this

Comment: Thank you.  This was not my issue but I very much appreciate your time everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me lay in the fact that I am modifying the Admin screen rather than the display of a Page or Post to viewers.

Replace:

```
 wp_enqueue_script(...)
```

With:

```
 admin_enqueue_script(...)
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included `wp_head()` in the `<head>` of your page? `wp_head()` will add your queued styles and scripts to the page.

Comment: Thank you.  This was not my issue but I very much appreciate your time.

Answer (score -1):

I have just tried this snippet in my site, and it is working properly. You may get conflict with some other plugin/code.

Also make sure you don't have any Cache enabled, and if so, try to clean up the cache. Also try to clean out your browser cache.

Finally, if non of the above works for you, try to de-activate your plugins, one by one in order to see if some of the plugins conflicts with this function, and in last step try to change theme, also to make sure the current theme doesn't conflict with this function.

Comment: Why downvoted ? Can somebody explain it ? While this snippet works fine on clean wordpress installation, he has to follow the rules provided by WordPress and this is what I have provide here.

Comment: There is no cache enabled nor any conceivable way a plugin would prevent HTML from rendering.  Please review WordPress documentation, the word Driver in the context of computer programming, and the use of tenses in English.  Thank you for your answer anyway.  PS: This was not my downvote.

Comment: Ok, I am not an English expert, but I know how WordPress works. I already know the WordPress documentation. The plugins do not prevent HTML to be rendered, but before a page get rendered, the many parts of the page live in Objects, Arrays and variables. By this, a plugin, may can "damage" the object hold's the CSS handlers before they get rendered in the HTML. PS: Thanks you didn't downvote my answer ;)

Comment: Additional, I try your excact code snippet in a clean WordPress installation and worked properly !! This mean something goes wrong with something else in your WordPress installation, and not the WordPress itself.

Comment: Thank you.  This was not my issue but I very much appreciate your time.

Comment: Finally did you found what was your issue ?